# How to connect WIFI printer to Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, wireless

I'm have just install Ubuntu 12.04 on my PS. I have WIFI printer and I want to connect it to my PC using Ubuntu. So my question is,
How can I connect WIFI printer to Ubuntu 12.04?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This should help you - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NetworkPrintingWithUbuntu. I hope this helps you.